# Unable to start app when deploying from azure pipeline

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a spring boot app to Azure app service. When I do it via maven in Intellij it works fine. It deploys and I can verify the app is deployed and started.

When I deploy it via azure pipeline and perform a release it simply fails to start the container. This is the output of the log:

```
2019-02-10T14:32:17.379283936Z /bin/init_container.sh: line 81: source: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
2019-02-10T14:32:17.379539843Z Startup File exited with code 126
```

I suspect it has to do with the section called

> startup command

in the deploy section. See the screenshot below. I mean, it is unclear if the jar is automatically started when I run the deployment or if you need to specify something here. I have tried with hardcoding `java -jar <name of jar file>` but got the same error. Is there something else that needs to be done? The release itself goes green but the container is never started.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and answer.

1. The startup command should indeed be empty.
2. I had to increase the container timeout value by setting the environment variable in Application Settings.

> WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT = 1800

Comment: Have to wait another 21 hours before I can do that.